# Downloading a file based on its base64 string

Tags: javascript, base64

I have a REST service that returns a base64 representation of a file, could be any variety (assuming for now its application/pdf), and am wondering if there's a simple way to trigger the browser to save that base64 string into a file download that can be processed within JavaScript. I've looked at [download.js](http://danml.com/download.html) but it doesn't seem to do what I intend it to do, unless its tied to a click event (something I really can't do here). Are there any other suggestions to implement this?

Comment: Do you have have control over the server?

Comment: I do, but from what i've been told by our project manager, this should be done within the browser due to their interpretation of the requirements and regulations on the manner in which data should be retrieved. I know. It's really weird.

Comment: I would tell them that you don't want base64 it's 33% larger in size and more process to handle